# Need help to fit an exponential function to the data

Tags: fitting

I have a problem with fitting an exponential function to the data. I used the NonlinearModelFit function to perform the fit. The code plots the fit but not the data and the standard error for the fit parameters is high. The code is as follows:

```
    data = {{261, 10}, {262, 50}, {263, 100}, {264, 1000}};
    fun2[x_] = a*Exp[-b/(x - c)];
    nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {fun2[x], 0.8 > a> 0, 200 > b> 29, 
    290 > c> 265}, {{a, 0.4}, {b, 25}, {c, 270}}, x];
    nlm[{"BestFit", "ParameterTable"}];
    rf[f_] := Normal[nlm];
    Show[Plot[rf[x], {x, 0, 270}], ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> "O"]]
```

Comment: You need to change the plot range of your plotting function `Plot[rf[x], {x, 0, 270}, PlotRange -> {{260, 265}, {0, 1020}}]` in order to see the data points. `Plot` is zooming in on what it thinks the interesting part is, and the plot range of the `ListPlot` is not considered. Also, you should expect the standard error to be very high. You're trying to fit a 3 parameter model with 4 data points, which is a bad idea in most cases. You should also be a bit wary that the fit found your b-parameter to be exactly 29. This probably means your constraints are too tight or not enough data.

Comment: You shouldn't be estimating 4 parameters (a, b, c, and error variance) with just 4 data points.

Comment: Thanks! MassDefect1

Comment: And this will show you the points in addition to the curve: Plot[rf[x], {x, 0, 270}, PlotRange -> {{260, 265}, {0, 1020}}, 
 Epilog -> {Orange, PointSize[.02], Point[data]}]

Comment: Seems like it might be more amenable to fitting log(f(x)).